# Using Excel to Filter Unwanted Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am completely stuck on an issue that I'm afraid has an easy solution, but that I'm over complicating.  Hoping to get some new insight here.

I have two columns in Excel, each are formatted as dates.  In both column, the dates are reported every 60 seconds; HOWEVER, one of the columns has missing data.  I would like to line the columns up, which I thought could be done using "INDEX(MATCH)" but that is getting me no where.  See the screenshot:[image]

What I'm trying to do in column "F" is line up the values in column "B" with its corresponding date in column "C".  Where there is a "#N/A" in the screenshot, that should instead read "1104".

Is the "INDEX(MATCH)" approach not appropriate here?

Let me know if I need to clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is somewhat backwards.

Try this:
`=INDEX($B$3:$B$13, MATCH(C9, $A$3:$A$13, 0))`

The syntax is:
`=INDEX(the array where my return value is located, MATCH(the reference value I want to find, the array where my reference value is located))`

The essential error is that you had columns A and C in the wrong order inside your `MATCH` formula - you told Excel to look for values from col A somewhere within col C, which results in `#N/A` when the value in col A doesn't exist in col C (which is the case for 5min timestamp in `A8`). It's also the reason most of your actually filtered data (from row 8 and down) is wrong.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for the help!  I sometimes get mixed up when using this approach as it can be a little confusing.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the flare data recorder date column is complete.  One approach to your problem would be to use `VLOOKUP` on the flare date against the EPP date column adjacent to its data column, and rebuild that second data column the way you want.

Insert a new column in between the current `B` and `C`, such the new column becomes an empty column `C`.  Then enter the following formula into `C3`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,D$3:E$100,2,FALSE),"no match")
```

The basic idea here is to lookup each complete date against the EPP data recorder data set, and then fetch the corresponding flow rate value from the (currently) column `D`.  My formula would report `no match` should a date have no EPP flow data.